# Receiving Post data (not form) in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, post

I am getting a string through a prompt and I want to send it from the client to my server (Which uses Express).

Client:

```
username = prompt('Enter your Username');
req.open('POST', url + 'username');
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode;charset=UTF-8');
req.send(username);
```

Server:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.post('/username', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.end('ok bud');
});
```

And the result of req.body is always {} when the username var is something like 'test' or something. If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your content type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencode;charset=UTF-8'
Which requires the payload to be in key value pairs.

Since you want to post plain text, set your content type to 'text/plain' instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching username in your post request at client side which was taken through prompt.

Comment: Sorry I missed last line

Comment: I missed req.send(username) this line while reading your question.